# how to test for rootState.loading?

Tags: ember.js

I am initially loading partial information for some objects (called Script) and then retrieve the full records when needed. For this, I am using

```
App.ScriptRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
       return {id: params.script_id};
    },
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
      var record = App.Script.find(model.id);
      record.reload();
      controller.set("model", record);
    },
);
```

This works great for the situation stated above: script objects are preloaded and I am reloading a script with full details. If I refresh the page or access it directly by url, however, we do not have a preloaded set of objects and the script object is loaded for the first time and I get the following error:

```
Error while loading route:
Error: Attempted to handle event `reloadRecord` on App.Script:ember281:StudioMRConverter> while in state rootState.loading.
```

How can I modify my setupController to test for `rootState.loading` before I call `record.reload()`?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you might listen first to the `didLoad` event [(model lifecycle)](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/model-lifecycle/) before doing a reload of the record.

For example:

```
App.ScriptRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
   return {id: params.script_id};
  },
  setupController: function(controller, model) {
    var record = App.Script.find(model.id);
    record.on('didLoad', function() {
      record.reload();
    });
    controller.set("model", record);
  },
);
```

Comment: Mmh, this fixes the reload on refresh, but I lose the reload in all other situations. Does it somehow go against Ember philosophy to do only partial loading of models? Or is there some way to completely remove or invalidate a partially loaded model before I place the call to App.Script.find(model.id)?

Comment: Or maybe I should define two different models, such as App.PartialScript and App.Script to maintain the partially loaded records in a different namespace from the fully loaded ones? But that does not seem right...

Comment: I'm not sure, can you post how your models do look like at the moment?

Comment: I just updated the fiddle. I added a new Model called App.Partialscript, which is a scaled-down version of App.Script; this way, the fully loaded Script object does not collide with the preloaded partial script. This setup works: (a) the overview route '/scripts' loads an array of "partialscripts" that have the same id as the "normal" script objects, and the partialscripts link to '/scripts/SCRIPTID'. (b) clicking on the link queries for a fully loaded script object, which is supplied via App.Script. (c) refreshing and accessing the '/#/scripts/SCRIPTID' are also backed by App.Script.

Comment: @philstra, if your models allow you to split it up, then it's looks like a viable solution

Comment: yes, it works, but it feels like a hack - the Partialscript is *really* the same entity as the Script, so should there not be a way to express that equality in Ember?

Comment: @philstra, I'll give you an upvote to make your question bubble up and attract more eyes, hopefully some other ember guru can provide a more emberish solution to your problem